# Module available but not reported as installed

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

Using PowerShell (version 5.1.17134.228), found some unexpected differences between `Get-Module` and `Get-InstalledModule`, in that some modules that I'd expect to be returned by `Get-InstalledModule` are not.

As an example:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name 'Hyper-V'

Get-InstalledModule -Name 'Hyper-V'
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name 'Hyper-V'


    Directory: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name      ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----      ----------------
Binary     2.0.0.0    Hyper-V   {Add-VMAssignableDevice, Add-VMDvdDrive, Add-VMFibreChannelHba, Add-VMGpuPartitionAdapter...}
Binary     1.1        Hyper-V   {Add-VMDvdDrive, Add-VMFibreChannelHba, Add-VMHardDiskDrive, Add-VMMigrationNetwork...}


PS C:\> Get-InstalledModule -Name 'Hyper-V'
PackageManagement\Get-Package : No match was found for the specified search
criteria and module names 'Hyper-V'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.6.5\PSModule.psm1:9125 char:9
+         PackageManagement\Get-Package @PSBoundParameters | Microsoft. ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...lets.GetPackage:GetPackage) [Get-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.GetPackage
```

As you can see, the `Get-Module` command is returning a local path of the Hyper-V modules, so it's definitely installed locally, but `Get-InstalledModule` cannot find the module.

Is this a bug or have I misunderstood what `Get-InstalledModule` is meant to do?

Comment: `Get-InstalledModule` can only return what `Install-Module` has installed. The Hyper-V cmdlets aren't installed that way, but with `Install-WindowsFeature`. Basically, you wouldn't expect `Get-InstalledModule` to return any "standard" modules.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jeroen. Not ideal (as from a user's point of view I doubt it matters how the module was installed), but at least the reason behind the current output is clearer.

Comment: I've never used `Get-InstalledModule` :)